# Java says there is no main method even though I defined it

Tags: java, program-entry-point, minecraft

I made a Minecraft mod a few months back and it was working fine. Now it doesn't work. It gives this error.

> Error: Main method not found in class occmod.Main, please define the main method as:public static void main(String[] args)
>   or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

So I added a main method as per the error message and it still gives the same error message.

This is my code:

```java
package occmod;

import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.SidedProxy;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPostInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
import occmod.proxies.CommonProxy;
import occmod.tabs.ChickenTab;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.init.Items;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;


/*  MOD INFO */
@Mod(modid = Reference.MOD_ID, name = Reference.NAME, version = Reference.VERSION)  
//***

public class Main {

    // I added this block of code and it still gives the same error 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("test");
        return;
    }

 // CREATIVE TAB INSTANTIATION

    public static Main instance;
    public static final CreativeTabs chickentab = new ChickenTab("chickentab");
    public static CreativeTabs chickentab_1;



//PROXY INFO
    @SidedProxy(clientSide = Reference.CLIENT_PROXY, serverSide = Reference.COMMON_PROXY)
    public static CommonProxy proxy;
//***


    @EventHandler
    public static void PreInt(FMLPreInitializationEvent event) {
        proxy.PreInt(event);

    }
    @EventHandler
    public static void init(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
        proxy.init(event);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public static void postinit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event) {
        proxy.postinit(event);   
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: "and it was working fine. Now it doesn't." What did you change? Did you save/recompile the code?

Comment: What error are you getting right now?

Comment: but you know that a MOD is not a program that runs by itself... it should be loaded by Minecraft (actually by Forge) (anyway, are you sure that the class got compiled **and** you are running the correct one (from correct directory) - or is Java still finding the old one?)

Comment: You probably need to extend your application as per the error message, because the mod is not an individual application. I has to be loaded by the Minecraft app

Comment: @Stultuske I didn't change anything, then when I got the error message, I added the main method and it still gives the same error.

Comment: @rahul obviously, something changed. maybe the code, maybe the version of your java, ... anything. if you have code that runs on day one, and nothing changes, it still runs on day 2.

Comment: @Psychotechnopath I get the exact same error with or without the main method (this error: Error: Main method not found in class occmod.Main, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application)

Comment: @Shantanu When I ran it on eclipse from the project directory, it used to open Minecraft with the mod loaded

Comment: @Stultuske My code didn't change. I think the java version might have changed

Comment: Sounds like your run configuration got messed up.

Comment: @Draco18s Any ideas on how I can figure out if that is the problem?

Comment: Go to edit your run configurations and check that the run configuration  you're attemping to use it pointed at `net.minecraftforge.userdev.LaunchTesting` (or similar, the naming has changed at least once, and I pulled this from my 1.14 environment).